# ModelForm won't validate because missing field is assigned in clean()

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `ModelForm` with a custom save method to populate a model field with a kwarg from the url params (that was passed to the form):

```
from app.models import MyModel
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fk_customer = kwargs.pop('customer')
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyModelForm, self).clean()
        cleaned_data['fk_customer'] = self.fk_customer
        return cleaned_data
```

When I inspect `cleaned_data` in my view, `fk_customer` is present and valid. However `is_valid()` is false, and the `ModelForm` won't `save()`. If I override a few things and force save, the field `fk_customer` is saved as `None`.

What's going on and how can I alter `cleaned_data` and still validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not displaying the `customer` field from your form, then you should exclude it from your form class instead of using `__all__`.

Then, I would try to set the customer in the form's `save` method instead of the `clean` method. The following is untested:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.customer = kwargs.pop('customer')
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('customer',)


    def save(self, commit=True)
        instance = super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.customer = self.customer
        if commit:
            instance.save()
            self.save_m2m()
        return instance
```